# Identity Server - Add Service Provider blank page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to setup Identity Server as SSO provider for my DRUPAL website, according to this URL :

https://medium.com/@iwantha/wso2-identity-server-sso-with-drupal-8-4bb8ae915c20

However, when I came to "Configuring Service Provider" section :

[image]

My Identity Server gives a blank page for the "Add" button (/carbon/application/add-service-provider.jsp)

[image]

Comment: Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: What is the identity server version you use? and can you provide the error logs if there any error logs are printed in the carbon console?